# How to find child in dictionary with unknown depth?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wish to search this JSON dictionary for the child which has a key "title" with value "Controller". Then, when found, I wish to grab the value from the key "tid" of this child. In the example dictionary below, the value would be "7".

The child "Controller" may end up at a different depth in the tree.

This is JSON. I am stuck at finding a way of iterating through an unknown depth of children.

```
  {
  "users": {
   "fredrik": {
    "J1312160092": {
     "data": {
         "somedata": 0,
         "someotherdata": [36, 1, 2, 0]
      },

     "children": [
        { "#": "T1",
           "children": [
              { "#": "T2",
                 "children": [
                    { "#": "T3",
                       "children": [
                          { "#": "T4",
                             "children": [],
                             "data": {
                                "tid": 4,
                                "title": "Pre-job: Sub-task 1",
                                "state": "+D",
                                "cids": [1]
                             }
                          },
                          { "#": "T5",
                             "children": [],
                             "data": {
                                "tid": 5,
                                "title": "Pre-job: Sub-task 2",
                                "state": "+D",
                                "cids": [2]
                             }
                          }
                       ],
                       "data": {
                          "serialsubtasks": 0,
                          "tid": 3,
                          "title": "Pre-job",
                          "state": "+A",
                          "cids": [3]
                       }
                    },
                    { "#": "T6",
                       "children": [
                          { "#": "T7",
                             "children": [
                                { "#": "T8",
                                   "children": [],
                                   "data": {
                                      "tid": 8,
                                      "title": "Master: Frame 1-1, camera(s): camera1, camera2",
                                      "state": "-B",
                                      "cids": [4]
                                   }
                                }
                             ],
                             "data": {
                                "tid": 7,
                                "title": "Controller",
                                "state": "-B",
                                "cids": [5]
                             }
                          },
                          { "#": "T9",
                             "children": [
                                { "#": "T10",
                                   "children": [],
                                   "data": {
                                      "tid": 10,
                                      "title": "Frame 1",
                                      "state": "-B",
                                      "cids": [6]
                                   }
                                },
                                { "#": "T11",
                                   "children": [],
                                   "data": {
                                      "tid": 11,
                                      "title": "Frame 2",
                                      "state": "-B",
                                      "cids": [7]
                                   }
                                },
                                { "#": "T12",
                                   "children": [],
                                   "data": {
                                      "tid": 12,
                                      "title": "Frame 3",
                                      "state": "-B",
                                      "cids": [8]
                                   }
                                }
                             ],
                             "data": {
                                "tid": 9,
                                "title": "Frame holder",
                                "state": "-B"
                             }
                          }
                       ],
                       "data": {
                          "serialsubtasks": 0,
                          "tid": 6,
                          "title": "Frame job",
                          "state": "-B"
                       }
                    }
                 ],
                 "data": {
                    "serialsubtasks": 1,
                    "tid": 2,
                    "title": "Blocker",
                    "state": "-B"
                 }
              }
           ],
           "data": {
              "tid": 1,
              "title": "Main job",
              "state": "-B"
           }
        }
     ]
  }

   }
  },
  "recordlimit": {"limit": 1, "truncated": 0}
  }
```

Comment: Define _find_. find its parents, its key, its depth?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wish to find the value of its "tid" key.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, could you give one or two concrete examples of input and output? Also, is this JSON?

Comment: This is JSON. I am stuck at trying to iterate through all children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recurse your json and look for controller. This snippet should be agnostic to the json's structure, transverse both child lists and dictionaries and yield the tid of the first dictionary containing a key "title" with the value of "Controller".

```
def findTid (j):
    if isinstance (j, dict):
        if 'title' in j and j ['title'] == 'Controller':
            return j ['tid']
        for v in j.values ():
            r = findTid (v)
            if r: return r
    if isinstance (j, list):
        for e in j:
            r = findTid (e)
            if r: return r
```

Called with your data it returns '7'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a recursive function something along this lines:

```
def find(tree):
    if tree["data"]["title"] == "Controller":
         return tree["data"]["tid"]
    if "children" in tree:
        return 
    for child in tree["children"]:
        f = find(child)
        if f:
             return f
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a regular expression and the re.findall with the pattern you are looking for in the tree.